# More prominent indication that this site is for research-level questions?

Tags: discussion, site-general

I noticed that we get a fair number of non-research-level questions.  This is not too surprising, since if someone comes here and just looks at the title of the site, they might get the wrong impression.

Suggestion: Add some text to the "Ask a Question" page to clarify this.  For instance, on the sidebar it currently says "Is your question about theoretical computer science?  We prefer questions that can be answered, not just discussed."

Perhaps this could be revised to "Is your question about theoretical computer science?  We prefer questions that can be answered, not just discussed.  We prefer questions at a research level." Would this help avoid confusion, or do you think people would just overlook that?

See also: [Limiting non research level questions](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1603/5038) (which seems like an even better suggestion, but apparently has not been implemented).

Comment: I have forgotten how to edit these sections.

Comment: I am not sure we can edit them.

Comment: Our FAQ link used to go straight to the customized description, but now it is just goes to the generic help thingie.  The FAQ seems to now live at http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic (and it might be worth updating the boilerplates).

Comment: @András, I agree. But I think the idea is that people don't read the [FAQ] unless there face a problem. The first paragraphs of the [about] page is the place to explain the scope of the site in the new system.

Comment: I think this suggestion is good. I would add a link to cs.stackexchange.com to make it clear that there is a different site at which one can ask non-research-level questions. If we can just get new users to click on that link, they will probably figure out quickly which site is more appropriate.