# Mentioning "research-level" in "How to Ask"

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

It's been [pointed out](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/19917/graph-isomorphism-polynomial-time-reduction-from-gi-for-disconnected-graphs-to?noredirect=1#comment52499_19917) that the "How to Ask" box that appears when a user is [asking a question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) doesn't mention that TCS Stack Exchange is for research-level questions only.  Is that something we can change or is it fixed by the powers that be?

Comment: It would also be nice if the statement on an empty title line also included "research-level".

Comment: Anna said she will follow it up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've changed the topic description for this site to "research-level theoretical computer science".

Ask question title prompt:

[image: What's your research-level theoretical computer science question? Be specific.]

Ask question sidebar:

[image: Is your question about research-level theoretical computer science?]

Comment: Thank you Shog9. :)

Answer (score 3):

I agree completely.  I suggested something similar [earlier this year](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2697/5038), but it never got implemented.  I still think it's worth a try, and I like your suggestion.

As it happens, it looks like something similar had been [previously requested](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1603/5038) back in 2012, but that never got implemented either.

Maybe if we can get some attention from the StackExchange team, they can help us figure out how to edit the information in the "How to Ask" box.

Comment: We cannot edit it, only SE admins can. I pinged them.